# enum vs boolean in case of multiple yes/no fields

Tags: mysql

I want to store information from a form where there are multiple yes/No question. For those how should I create table fields? I have experienced mysql doesn't support multiple columns to have same ENUM values. So I can't assign `'yes','no'` for more than one column.

If I use boolean? how should I do it? Is it mandatory to have default values for boolean type field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like the enum datatype for [various reasons](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/).

Boolean in MySQL is actually a tinyint with 0 being false and 1 being true, or no and yes respectively.

```
BOOL, BOOLEAN

These types are synonyms for TINYINT(1). A value of zero is considered false. Nonzero values are considered true:

mysql> SELECT IF(0, 'true', 'false');
+------------------------+
| IF(0, 'true', 'false') |
+------------------------+
| false                  |
+------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(1, 'true', 'false');
+------------------------+
| IF(1, 'true', 'false') |
+------------------------+
| true                   |
+------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(2, 'true', 'false');
+------------------------+
| IF(2, 'true', 'false') |
+------------------------+
| true                   |
+------------------------+

However, the values TRUE and FALSE are merely aliases for 1 and 0, respectively, as shown here:

mysql> SELECT IF(0 = FALSE, 'true', 'false');
+--------------------------------+
| IF(0 = FALSE, 'true', 'false') |
+--------------------------------+
| true                           |
+--------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(1 = TRUE, 'true', 'false');
+-------------------------------+
| IF(1 = TRUE, 'true', 'false') |
+-------------------------------+
| true                          |
+-------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(2 = TRUE, 'true', 'false');
+-------------------------------+
| IF(2 = TRUE, 'true', 'false') |
+-------------------------------+
| false                         |
+-------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT IF(2 = FALSE, 'true', 'false');
+--------------------------------+
| IF(2 = FALSE, 'true', 'false') |
+--------------------------------+
| false                          |
+--------------------------------+

The last two statements display the results shown because 2 is equal to neither 1 nor 0.
```

[Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html).

FYI, this can be very useful for various other things. An example you can see in [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84283/7867) I recently gave.

Comment: You may want to add the option for the [`BIT` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bit-type.html), since the question is about multiple columns.